# Reactjs store addresses in array

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am working on user address management and saving it into mongodb like in addresses array but right now storing as object. Below is example of data want to store in DB.

```
        {
            "personname": "Customer_1",
            "mobile": "00000000000"
        },
        {
            "personname": "Customer_2",
            "mobile": "00000000001"
        }
```

```
  const [prifletab, setPrifletab] = useState(true);
  const [addressestab, setAddressestab] = useState(false);

  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    addresses: [],
    loading: false,
    error: false,
    redirectToProfile: false,
    formData: ""
  });

  return (
    <form className="mb-3" onSubmit={clickSubmit}>
      <h3>Profile Update </h3>
      <div
        className="prifletab"
        style={{ display: prifletab ? "block" : "none" }}
      >
        <div className="form-group">
          <label className="text-muted">Name</label>
          <input
            onChange={handleChange("name")}
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            value={name}
          />{" "}
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <label className="text-muted">Email</label>
          <input
            onChange={handleChange("email")}
            className="form-control"
            value={email}
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div
        className="addressestab"
        style={{ display: addressestab ? "block" : "none" }}
      >
        <div className="form-group">
          <label className="text-muted">Contact Person Name</label>
          <input
            onChange={handleChange("contactperson")}
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
          />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <label className="text-muted">Mobile</label>
          <input
            onChange={handleChange("contact")}
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <button className="btn btn-outline-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
```

I would like to request, if help me how to store array value in addresses array.  Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign value to `adrss` as if it's an object, however it's an array. If you just need to save one object to array, you can do it like so:

```
address = {[name]: event.target.value};
formData.set(addresses, [address]);
setValues({ ...values, addresses: [address] });
```

Or if you need to add an address instead of overwritting it:

```
setValues({ ...values, addresses: [...values.addresses, address] });
```

Comment: Thanks Clarity you got my vote but still i want to pass array data not object.   Would you like to help me regarding below code to pass array . 
        formData.set('addresses', {name: event.target.value});
        setValues({ ...values, 'addresses': {name: event.target.value} });

Comment: @skyrbs that's exactly what this code does, you construct the object first and then save it as array or add to existing array.

Comment: Thanks @clarity May be it is my mistake. What i want to store is like
addresses: Array
0: {
    "personname": "Customer_1",
    "mobile": "00000000000"
}
but it is storing like

addresses: Array
0:"[object Object]"

Comment: @skyrbs it would help if you added the code to the question to show how `handleChange` is called.

Comment: Thanks man for you kind helping nature. I just updated my question. You can see handle change and forms both.    Addresses details want to store in one array fields .

Comment: @skyrbs check this sandbox for how to handle the form in your case:https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-buck-g2fjc

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate you work.   Thank you.